# Morphtext jQuery plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've linked `jQuery`, `animate.css`, and `morphtext.js` in my document's `header`.

Within h1 I've created a span with the id '`js-rotating`'. I've then called it directly in the `html` like so

```
<script>
$("#js-rotating").Morphext({
animation: "bounceIn",
separator: ",",
speed: 2000,
complete: function () {
}
});
</script>
```

However, the plugin is not responding. I've verified that I can access the linked css and js files via the direct links. What could cause this issue?

Comment: Can you please create fiddle..

Comment: If you can share the whole html+js+css then we can look into it. Just put everything on jsfiddle and share the link

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? If so, what are they?

Comment: Also don't forget to check if you have only one JS library file included on the page.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I've got this one:
    morphext.min.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not    defined(anonymous function) @ morphext.min.js:1
jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.0:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.0

Comment: Have you included jQuery? I think probably not

Answer (score 3):

your code works perfectly for me,but the problem is that your script is executed before the complete loading of Dom.

to fix this issue,put your script inside **jQuery ready() Method** to ensure that the DOM is loaded properly before executing any functions.

```
    <script>
      $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#js-rotating").Morphext({
          animation: "bounceIn",
          separator: ",",
          speed: 2000,
          complete: function () {
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
```

this a [working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/z6JRrpt8JRiKmumEUUJS?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Your Theme is enqueueing jQuery 1.7.2:

And WordPress is enqueueing jQuery 1.8.3:

See also, Frank's answer regarding jQuery no-conflict mode.

Edit
WordPress bundles a version of jQuery. You will inevitably encounter problems if your Theme (or a Plugin) enqueues a separate version of jQuery - whether by enqueueing that separate jQuery version along side the WordPress-bundled version, or else by deregistering the core-bundled version, and enqueueing a custom version.

Don't register a custom version of jQuery via your Theme or any Plugins. If you need to use jQuery, just use the core-bundled version, via:

wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );